# How to cancel AWSTask<AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask *> request?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, awss3transfermanager

I am uploading a file like images in AWSS3 server and I can not cancel the request.

I have tried to cancel the request after upload task started. I am using `task.result.cancel()` method to cancel the task.

```
let awsTransferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.s3TransferUtility(forKey: AWSConfiguration.callbackKey)

        let task = awsTransferUtility!.uploadFile(url,
                                                  bucket: bucket,
                                                  key: key,
                                                  contentType: file.type.contentType,
                                                  expression: expression,
                                                  completionHandler: completionHandler)
            .continueWith(block: { (task) -> Any? in
                if task.error != nil {
                    completion(nil, task.error)
                }
                return nil
            }) as! AWSTask<AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask>
```

I just want to cancel the request and file won't upload on server.

Comment: Can anyone give the solution ASAP? Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/Classes/AWSS3TransferUtility.html#//api/name/uploadFile:bucket:key:contentType:expression:completionHandler:), you can obtain an instance of [`AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask`](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/Classes/AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask.html) by calling `task.result`.

> Returns an instance of AWSTask. On successful initialization, task.result contains an instance of AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask.

Then you should be able to call `cancel` on the `AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask` instance.

```
let task: AWSTask<AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask> = ...
let uploadTask: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask = task.result
uploadTask.cancel()
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check it out and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing but still facing the same issue can you check in my mac? using teamviewer.?

Comment: We can troubleshoot the problem the work out a solution together. Please join this chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194599/question-how-to-cancel-awstaskawss3transferutilityuploadtask-request

Comment: result is nil if connectivity is not present and completion call on .uploadFile(... never gets called. So can't cancel and completion never triggers either. Optional(<AWSTask: 0x2814cc480; completed = YES; cancelled = NO; faulted = YES; result = (null)>). Task is completed, but completion block never gets called. So, result is null (can't cancel) and completion never gets called makes it unhandleable....